# Assert4j: how to ignore fields based on actual values

Tags: java, comparison-operators, assertj

I've found ways to ignore fields based on names and types. Is it possible to ignore fields based on values. Like if I have an object

```
a.loc = @djhabds
b.loc = @892dfhs
```

Even though they are different, but they are memory locations so I don't care in my comparison.
I have many fields like this so I'd prefer a way to filter based on values instead of field names and types